# Getting remote git commit log without local copy

Tags: git

I want to get a copy of the commit log from a remote GIT repository **without** cloning/pulling it to my local machine and using only SSH. Is this possible?

For example, I want to do something like:

```
git log -- git@github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git
```

This will need to be generic. I know about the GitHub API (that was just an example); the command needs to work with any GIT repo that can be accessed over SSH.

Comment: Year 2021.. still no solution!

Answer (score 7):

> is this possible?

In short: no, not exactly. However, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178389/browse-and-display-files-in-a-git-repo-without-cloning has a nice alternative to running an SSH command remotely on the machine where the git repository lives.

It won't work with *any* git repo, just those where you are able to execute SSH commands against.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem so (at least easily right now -- maybe I could extend Git to make this possible).

I wrote a small script which makes a shallow clone into a temporary project, then runs `git log` and then removes the directory again. THe shallow cloning should hopefully be fast.

The script is here: https://github.com/albertz/helpers/blob/master/git-log-remote.sh

Comment: If you make a shallow clone with depth of 1, you'll only have the most recent commit in the log.